# Repository Level Restriction in Visual Studio Team Service

Tags: azure-devops, devops

We are planning to use the Visual Studio Team Service for our DevOps process. But the problem is we can not give restriction  in repository  level. In Visual Studio Team Service , restriction can be implemented in project level, We want to create all repository in one project so that we can easily manage our scrum board. Now how can we give repository level restriction like GitHub or Bitbucket where only assigned team member can only see the repository ?

Comment: What's the result now? Do you solve it with my way?

Comment: Yes, I am adding all member in every repository and add permission for every member. In this way I am fulfilling my requirement at this moment . 
Thanks for reply . And sorry for late reply , was busy with other works .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to these steps to set permission:

1.Add users to your VSTS (https://XXX.visualstudio.com/_user) (I turn off the feature of Streamlined User Management)

2.Go to your Git team project admin page and select version control (https://XXX.visualstudio.com/[teamproject]/_admin/_versioncontrol)

3.Select a repository

4.In Security page, click Add > Add user to add members

5.Grant these users Contribute and Read permission

Note: View instance-level information (For connection in Visual Studio) and View project-level information are needed too.

More information about permission, you can refer to this article: Permissions [and groups defined for Team Services and TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions#git-repository-permissions-object-level)

Comment: A bit late, but does this prevent the user from seeing the repository at all or just being able to see the contents of the repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can set permissions at the repository level. Look at the "Version Control" section of the administration area.

Comment: I had seen this before. Can you help me to find out the exact option from version control? There are lot of access control permission.